# Android: How to communicate between multiple intents

Tags: android, android-intent

I have three intents A, B, C:

[image: Activity Map]

I call intent B from A and the C from B. In intent C, I saved a record in database and now I want the user redirected to A. I used Activity for result method in A.

Any good tutorial or link for understanding the above.

P.S: I am a novice in android development.

Comment: again call A from C activity after saved in db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)

When C saves the data, return a success code to B.
Then call finish() on B when this success code is received.
You will see A now.

If you want to inform A about the save success. Then do the same startActivityForResult between A and B.